# Is it possible to have iPhone messages with drafts visibly marked as such?

Tags: iphone, sms

I recently switched from Android to iOS and am still getting used to the changes in the operating systems.

In Android - or at least in Samsung's flavour of it - if I looked at a list of my text message conversations grouped by contact, any conversation that had a draft in it is clearly marked as such.

Here's an example:

[image]

I communicate via text a lot, and I found this a handy way of marking whether or not someone was awaiting a response I had yet to send.

I cannot seem to find an equivalent function in iOS. Is there a setting, app or widget that does this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not a feature of **Messages** in iOS.  If you started typing a response to someone but didn't send it yet, that text will still be in the text box when you go back to that message.